# Registro de datos con select en laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

Tengo un problema y he investigado por todos lados y no se como solucionarlo...
Tengo un formulario que tiene un input y un select. He aquí que el problema aparece cuando quiero guardar el registro en la base de datos.. cuando hago el click en el botón guardar me sale el siguiente error:

```
"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'provincia' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `localidad` (`localidad`, `provincia`, `updated_at`, ` ▶"
```

el campo provincia es el que tengo select trayendo los datos de la tabla provincia. cual puede ser el error...

Código del Modelo:

```
<?php 
 namespace App;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 class Localidad extends Model
 {
protected $fillable = [
    'localidad',
    'provincia'
    ];
    protected $table  = 'localidad';
}
```

Código del Controlador:

```
   public function create()
{


    //aqui debes enviarla la info que va llenar el select
    $provincias = provincia::all();

    return view('localidades.create', compact('provincias')); //con eso ya tenemos la info pa llenar el select
}

public function create_post(Request $request)
{
    $crearNuevaLocalidad = localidad::create([
        'localidad' => $request->Input('localidad'),
        'provincia' => $request->Input('provincia'),
        'estado' => 1
    ]);

    if($crearNuevalocalidad->save())
    {
        return back()->with('status','La localidad ingresada se ha registrado satisfactoriamente');
    }
    else
    {
        return 'ha ocudrrido un error';
    }
}
```

Código de la vista

```
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <!-- form start -->
        <div class="box-body">
        @if ($errors->any())
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
          <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
  </div><br />
@endif
      <form method="post" action="{{route('create_localidad')}}">
            <div class="form-group">
              @csrf
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Localidad</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="localidad"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="provincia">Seleccione la Provincia</label>
              <select class="form-control">
                @foreach($provincias as $provincia)
                <option>{{$provincia->provincia}}</option>
                @endforeach
              </select>
            </div>
            <a class="btn btn-danger"  href="#" value="Cancelar">Cancelar</a>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  value="crear"> 
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Rutas

```
    Route::get('localidad/create','LocalidadController@create');
    Route::post('localidad/create','LocalidadController@create_post')- 
    >name('create_localidad');
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código pertinente: controlador, vista y hasta modelo/migración.

Comment: A tu select le hace falta el atributo name y pasarle como valor provincia

Comment: Y al option el atributo value para indicar de cada elemento iterado que propiedad recogerá si el id o el nombre

Comment: @Aprendiz ya solucione esa parte gracias a tu ayuda.. ahora me salta un error nuevo, que en el campo estado no tiene valor definido siendo que en el controlador le puse 'estado' => 1

Comment: Agrega el código donde dices teber establecido dicho valor

Comment: @Aprendiz:

  $crearNuevaLocalidad = localidad::create([
        'localidad' => $request->Input('localidad'),
        'provincia' => $request->Input('provincia'),
        'estado' => 1
    ]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viendo el codigo a simple vista se ve que le falta el nombre al selector, por esta razon, el valor de este no esta llegando a tu controlador.

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('create_localidad')}}">
    <div class="form-group">
      @csrf
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Localidad</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="localidad"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="provincia">Seleccione la Provincia</label>
      <select class="form-control">
        @foreach($provincias as $provincia)
        <option>{{$provincia->provincia}}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-danger"  href="#" value="Cancelar">Cancelar</a>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  value="crear"> 
  </div>
</form>
```

Donde en el selector lo dejaría de la siguiente manera
`<select class="form-control" name="provincia">`

Comment: Tenia la misma pregunta y me soluciono la respuesta que dieron gracias !